# Do "How do I get from problem to algorithm?" questions have a place on CodeGolf.SE?

Tags: discussion, challenges

We've [seen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/3019/78) several [migrations](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/3047/78) from [Stack](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/2774/78) Overflow recently (including [one that was eventually un-migrated](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6473218/2509)), and it is clear that not everyone on Stack Overflow understands the fairly restrictive rules we have established here.

*OK, so that's not a big surprise. Moderators from all the computery sites have been on the mother meta complaining about being “Stack Overflow's waste bin” from time to time.*

I have noticed a commonality in some of the recent migrations: they are—stripped of their verbal confusion—questions about dissecting a problem and choosing algorithms that will work.

I assert that that is a basic Programming Puzzles skill, and wonder if these problems might have a place here similar to the *“Tips for golfing in ...”* series?

Thought?

If we are going to accept them should they be Community Wiki?

Comment: the un-migration was due to a particularly boneheaded OP though. Protip: don't include an explicit call for a coding challenge unless you *really mean it*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I have noticed a commonality in some of the recent migrations: they are---striped of their verbal confusion---question about dissecting a problem and choosing algorithms that will work.
>
> assert that that is a basic Programming Puzzles skill, and wonder if these problems might have a place here similar to the "Tips for golfing in..." series?

It's not a basic programming puzzles skill: it's a basic programming skill. As far as that aspect of the questions goes, they're at home in SO - its FAQ says that it covers questions which relate to (among others)

> - a specific programming problem
> - a software algorithm

The aspect which I think ties together the questions which are being migrated here is that they're not business questions. I think some people see a question which is about problems people face in programming for pleasure rather than business and think it doesn't belong on SO. But there's nothing in the SO FAQ against such questions, as long as they relate to an actual problem faced. I think the SO Meta is the place to raise this, and I'll raise it there if people agree and no-one else does it.

Update: [now raised](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/97342/is-stackoverflow-limited-to-business-questions).

Comment: Do you think [my question](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/400/correctly-implement-the-exon-chaining-algorithm) should be on StackOverflow?  I'm not sure, after reading this.

Comment: @Matthew, yes. I think if you posted it now it would probably be migrated.